# combine netcat with chat on bash for automatic udp responses

Tags: linux, bash, chat, netcat

I want to combine "chat" and "nc" on linux, so I will create a tiny udp server that responds on a specific request and sends back an answer.

In fact I want to redirect the stdout of "nc" to the stdin of "chat" and vice versa. My first attempt was:

```
nc -w 3000 -u -n -l -p 30000 >&1111 <2222 & 
chat -V 'request' 'answer' >&2222 <1111
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I believe file descriptors have to be between 0 and 255. You should probably use named pipes instead anyway.

Answer (score 3):

use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES) instead of netcat. Something like this :

```
socat UDP-LISTEN:5555 EXEC:"chat -sv ping pong",pty
```

To test it, you can open another terminal, and use socat to bridge stdio and an UDP socket :

```
socat - UDP:localhost:5555
```

Type ping, and you will get pong !